# Entity Framework initializer in console/library app

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am currently working on a project with has a console app and few library projects. One library project is a EF code first project which contains my models and the context:

```
public class MyDbContext: DbContext
    {        
        public MyDbContext() : base("MyConnectionString")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }
    }
```

I also have a singleton class through which I want to access the database. The singleton looks like this:

```
public sealed class DbLogger : IDbLogger
    {
        private static readonly DbLogger instance = new DbLogger();
        private static MyDbContext ctx = new MyDbContext();        

        static DbLogger() {
            Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new DbInitializer());
        }

        private DbLogger() { }

        public static DbLogger Instance
        {
            get {
                return instance;
            }
        }

        public void AddFile(string fileName)
        {
            ctx.Files.Add(new File() { FullPath = fileName });
        }
    }
```

The db initializer is very simple and just implements the CreateDatabaseIfNotExists. Nothing is done in Seed yet.

In the console all which references the library project I just want to use it as:

```
private DbLogger logger = DbLogger.Instance;
```

and call the logger from a Task using:

```
logger.AddFile("myFileName");
```

When the app gets to logger.AddFile call I get the following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The context cannot be used while the model is
>   being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used
>   inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is
>   accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members
>   of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

How can I delay the using of the context until the model was created?
I am currently a bit stuck with this and any idea on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend this approach

```
public void AddFile(string fileName){
    using(var ctx = new MyDbContext() ){
        ctx.Files.Add(new File() { FullPath = fileName });
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

You should only use the DbContext when needed. Open the DB connection, interact with the DB and close the connection. The using statement take care of the opening and closing of the DB connection.

**EDIT** - updated with SaveChanges()

Comment: this worked like a charm! However, is it possible to explain why this works and my previous code wasn't? Would be great if I could understand what's the difference between them.

Comment: You probably meant `ctx.SaveChanges()`.

Comment: @Kunukn I am aware of the using construct and what it does. My issue is more of why if I try to initialize the context in the static constructor it's not working and if I do it in the methods as you told me it does work. Also, I'm not sure I'm comfortable using this construct in case of 1000 files that need to be save to DB...

Comment: @AndreiC in case of 1000 files won't do any different, you will make 1000 request to the DB either way.

Answer (score 0):

ad to @Kunukn answer:

I think that you should blame

```
private static MyDbContext ctx = new MyDbContext();
```

It was trying to acces context before database initializer run.

If you don't wan't to create new context on every AddFile() call, try create context in static constructor.

Comment: I tried that before posting the question here... it didn't work. That's why I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

I see problem with line

Database.SetInitializer(new DbInitializer());

if you use

```
public void AddFile(string fileName){
    using(var ctx = new MyDbContext() ){
        ctx.Files.Add(new File() { FullPath = fileName });
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

then your purpose of singleton is not getting solved because it will create a new MyDbContext every time AddFile is called ( and this is recommended)

but even if you insist on having a single dbcontext object then you should create some 
initialization fucntion and might be call it after object is created.

might be something like

```
private DbLogger logger = DbLogger.Instance;
logger.Initialize()
```